# Fast binary reading and writing issue regarding 'conflicting' binary formats

Tags: c#, matlab, file-io, binary, memory-mapping

I am struggling with the processing of binary (file) data (in c#). This is the situation:

- I have a binary file that can be as small as 1 MB and as large as 60 GB, hence impossible to fit in memory (assume slow laptop with 2 GB ram, both running 32 and 64 bit windows). This file contains data from, for example, 20 sources along a time base. The file's header does not inform me about the length of the signals, meaning that the length of each signal can (and most of the wime will) differ. Therefore I do not know the amount of bytes that one signal contains on forehand. Also note that the data is unevenly spaced along the file. Therefore I have to search for identifiers (2 bytes) in the file that matches the corresponding signal sample.
- Secondly I need to process and store this data in a new binary file. The file size will be roughly the same. But the binary format is completely different. In fact it is a Matlab binary file format.

These are the challenges:

- Since the Matlab binary requires the signal length (given as the number of bytes) in the header of the signal I need to know the length on forehand. Or alternatively seek back in the written binary at the end and store the length then.
- The performance needs to be really good. Target is approaching the hard-disks r/w speed, hence CPU time needs to be low.
- Since the data will not fit in internal memory I need some sort block wise processing. But how to limit the block size correctly such that I will get no memory overflow exceptions while not sacrificing performance to much at the same time?

I already tried memory mapping of the file to read, but I am stuck with this since I would need to search along the complete file to know the length of the signals.

What would be a good approach to accomplish the above?

Comment: You need to determine the signal length so you can store it in the binary file. You question is to broad. Are you able to determine the signal strength? If you are unable to determine it ask this question, post the write and read code your currently using, including the data ( in hex ) your reading in. Be sure to explain the format and all the fields so we can help you.  From my point of view the only performance matrix you need to worry about is how quickly you can write the new file that would entirely depend on the hdd itself.  So lets just "solve" the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound and usr. Well determing the signals' length is a large part of the problem. Since this either requires loading the signal to a dynamic array (list) in memory or seeking through the binary file (e.g. 60 GB long) looking for identifiers and corresponding signals, accumulate their byte lengths for each and every signal (there can be hundreds of signals), and then start reading and writing data. This is what takes time since it requires every byte in the file to be read at least 2 times. Or does someone know a fast way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would repeatedly scan the entire input file sequentially. Each pass through the file, I would collect as many "signals" in memory as memory can hold. Once the working memory buffer is full I would write the collected "signals" into an output Matlab file and start again to collect more signals with the next pass. Once no more new signals were found the algorithm ends.

This algorithm requires multiple passes over the data for big files but at least it is sequential IO which is rather fast.

Answer (score 0):

How about a signal splitter? I would scan once through the file and create a new file for each new signal. During reading the huge file I would write the data to the right signal file. Memory is a non issue since you are always reading only one chunk from disk (about 4KB) which does not get you neary any memory boundary.

If you need some correlation between the signals you would need to insert some timepoint markers into the split files to analyze it time based. That should also be rather easy to do.

As added bonus you do know the signal length by reading its file length or if you do time based stuff I would write a header with the final signal length found during the splitting process.

Comment: Thanks Alois, but the prolbem with splitting the written files is that is gets more diffucult to load the data into Matlab. A file with a Matlab structure is preferred. The thing I am working on now is 'reading' the file twice. The first go is to get the memory adresses and signal lengths. The second to write the file. But again the problem of storing adresses is that the memory required for that is also large.